# c# Simulating user input on an Website

Tags: c#, html

On the website https://con.arbeitsagentur.de/prod/jobboerse/jobsuche-ui/ you can search for joboffers in germany via titel and location. I want to make an programm which automaticly fills in the formular.

The Problem: The `<input>` element used to fill in the location (id = wo-input) stops working if you asign an value to it using `Document.GetElementById("wo-input").SetAttribute("value", mylocation);`. That is because the website isnt actually using the value of the input as search parameter but rather uses an whitelist of locations. If you type something in the `<input>` field the website will present you an list of locations that resemble your input. You can then select one of the locations which will then be added to your search as tag.

Possible Solution: My idea would be to simulate the user input key by key and afterwards selecting the first entry in the lists which will always have the id=wo0. The problem here is that i have no idea how i would code that

Answer (score 0):

Try using fluent automation, you can target an input, type in it and click a button.

It's a testing framework, but does simulate a user input

https://github.com/stirno/FluentAutomation